# how to show one validation icon for radiobuttons group

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using knockoutjs and knockout validation plugin.

I would like to show one validation icon for the radio group, after 'Question 1' title.
How can I do this?

```
<label>Question 1:</label>
<div>
    <!-- ko foreach: answers -->
    <div>
        <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { value: id, id: id, name: 'answers' }, checked: $parent.selectedValue" />
        <label data-bind="text: text, attr: { for: id }"></label>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

There is an [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nSDC4/4/)

Also the second question - why validation icons are displaying always in this example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a validation message on another element by using the validationMessage binding handler:

This shows the **validation message**:

```
<label>Question 1:
    <span data-bind="validationMessage: selectedValue"></span>
```

This example shows a **custom message template**:

```
<label>Question 1:
        <input style="display:none" 
            data-bind="value:selectedValue, 
                       validationOptions: {messageTemplate: 'icon'}" />
</label>
```

Or more simply, if you want to use the **default messageTemplate**:

```
<label>Question 1:
        <input style="display:none" data-bind="value:selectedValue" />
</label>
```

As for the second question, the messageTemplate is processed whether the field is valid or not.  This allows you to show a validation message (say a green chackmark) while the field is valid, and show a validation error once it becomes invalid.

You can use the `if` binding handler in conjunction with the `field` variable to control when the message is visible.

```
<script type="text/html" id="icon">
    <span data-bind="if: field.isModified() && !field.isValid()">X<span>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just added validationMessage and made changes in the example. It's displaying the text message 'This field is required.' but I need the icon...

Comment: The resources for the fiddle example above were not wokring (GitHub no longer supplies it). So i updated with proper resources: http://jsfiddle.net/nSDC4/12/

Comment: that link returns 404